# Keep checkbox position in form when resizing window

Tags: html, forms, css, checkbox, position

```css
.left-col {
    width:25%; }

    label {
    width:100%; 
    position:relative; }

    input[type="checkbox"] + div::before {
     right:-35px !important;
      left: auto !important; }

     input[type="checkbox"] + div::after {
     left: auto !important;
      right: -33px !important;
       width: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="left-col"> <label>
    <span>text</span>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <div></div>
    </label> </div>
```

I have two columns form. I have checkbox with div pseudo class inside the label. I need checkbox to be positioned in right column and still be inside label. 
Problem is, I can't change it such a way, that checkbox would be inside label AND would stay at the same position when resizing window.

I could keep checkbox with negative right property so it doesn't change position when resizing, but then it's outside label and unclickable.

I can change width of label - but then checkbox jumps when resizing.

Is there any way to solve this with CSS?

checkbox position without negative right when resizing:

[image]

checkbox position I need:

[image]

Comment: Why exactly do you need the input to be inside the label?

Comment: Because same checkbox html model is used in different parts of app, where it is convenient if user can click on text of the label and "activate" checkbox.

Comment: Alright, but it is more convenient to give the input an `id` and use the `for` attribute of the label. That way you can put the label where ever you want. This even might work for your case right here, try it.

Comment: Yep, it is in use already(with Angular) - different "for" and "id" for each checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing the width of .left-col to 100% (on checkboxes line) and then adjusting margins and paddings of span and label.

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in the comments, you can put the checkbox outside the label and use a `for` attribute to change its state. As for the alignment, it can be done like this.

```css
.left-col {
   display: block;
   width: 25%;
   position: relative;
}

label {
   display: inline;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
   position: absolute;
   display: inine;
   right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-col">
   <label for="idCheckbox">text</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="idCheckbox">
</div>
```